# Converting an ordered dictionary into a dataframe - Data handling - AliceBlue

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Newbie alert, please bear

the data i have right now after running the line of code below is

Input-

```py
data = pd.DataFrame(alice._AliceBlue__master_contracts_by_symbol)
```

Output-

```
    Index                                       NSE
1018GS2026 GS   Instrument(exchange='NSE', token=6833, symbol='1018GS2026 GS', name='GOI LOAN 10.18% 
                2026', expiry=None, lot_size='1')
1025GS2021 GS   Instrument(exchange='NSE', token=6819, symbol='1025GS2021 GS', name='GOI LOAN 10.25% 
                2021', expiry=None, lot_size='1')
116GS2020 GS    Instrument(exchange='NSE', token=6814, symbol='116GS2020 GS', name='GOI LOAN 11.60% 
                2020', expiry=None, lot_size='1')
182D010721 TB   Instrument(exchange='NSE', token=1776, symbol='182D010721 TB', name='GOI TBILL 182D- 
                01/07/21', expiry=None, lot_size='100')
182D020921 TB   Instrument(exchange='NSE', token=2593, symbol='182D020921 TB', name='GOI TBILL 182D- 
                02/09/21', expiry=None, lot_size='100')
```

I want a dataframe like this from inside the above dataframe

```
    Index      Exchange  token     symbol             name            expiry  lot_size 
1018GS2026 GS    NSE     6833   1018GS2026 GS  GOI LOAN 10.18% 2026    None      1
1025GS2021 GS    NSE     6819   1025GS2021 GS  GOI LOAN 10.25% 2021    None      1
116GS2020 GS     NSE     6814   116GS2020 GS   GOI LOAN 11.60% 2020    None      1
182D010721 TB    NSE     1776   182D010721 TB  GOI TBILL 182D-01/07/21 None     100
182D020921 TB    NSE     2593   182D020921 TB  GOI TBILL 182D-02/09/21 None     100
```

Any suggestions guys?, what should i do?
Note - alice._AliceBlue__master_contracts_by_symbol is an ordered dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
df = pd.json_normalize(df['NSE'])
```

If necessary convert named tuples to dictionaries by `_asdict` first:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(df['NSE'].apply(lambda x: x._asdict()))
```

Or:

```
df = pd.json_normalize([x._asdict() for x in df['NSE']]).set_index(df.index)
```

Comment: The last one worked, thanks a lot bro, means a lot